Локализация в ASP.NET Core Web API
Погуглив, написал такой код в Program.cs:
#region Localization
builder.Services.AddLocalization(option =>
{
    option.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
});

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "en", "ru" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
#endregion

app.UseRequestLocalization();

Папка Resources:

Я пытаюсь использовать локализацию так:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<AuthController> _localizer;

    public AuthController(IStringLocalizer<AuthController> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    public string Test()
    {
        return _localizer["About Title"];
    }
}

Пытался и ui-culture=ru приписывать к запросу и в Accept-Language писать ru, всё равно сервер возвращает "About Title":


